# saving data in a swift model

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I have a user model defined as follows :

```
class UserModel: NSObject {

var firsname: String?
var lastname: String?
var mail: String?

}
```

and in one of my http requests, I'm catching the json response as :

```
guard let mail = jsonArray[0]["mail"] as? String else { return }
```

So when I print the mail `print(mail)` it works fine and prints the correct mail string, but when I try to save that email in my user attributes, it gives me a `nil` value.

```
guard let mail = jsonArray[0]["mail"] as? String else { return }
    self.user?.mail = mail
    if let mailUnwrapped = self.user?.mail {
    print(mailUnwrapped)     // prints nil 
    }
```

am I missing something ? Any help please ! Thank you

Comment: It cannot print `nil` because it won't enter the if block if the value of `self.user?.mail` is `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to initialise user first before setting it's properties.
Try:

```
// First
self.user = UserModel()
// Then
guard let mail = jsonArray[0]["mail"] as? String else { return }
self.user?.mail = mail
```